# Multiscreen Support with res-values-dimensions

Tags: android, dimension, multiscreen

I have been using the layout-small, layout-large and such folders for multiscreen support but I was told to do with res-values-dimensions, but I am not sure how do it.

**How can you have Multiscreen support with res-values-dimensions?**

Answer (score 0):

you might try the following, if it just concerns dimensions and sizes. I didn't try it, but the main idea should work

1. make for every wished resolution a dimension file

   values.xml,
   values-hdpi.xml,
   values-xhdpi.xml,
2. inside each you can declare your values, eg:

> ```
> < resources >
> < bool name="myboolvalue" > true < /bool >
> < dimen  name="mydimenvalue" > dimension < /dimen >
> < /resources >
> ```

1. do this for every resolution. Then you can access these inside your layout, somehow like this:

> ```
> android:visibility="@bool/myboolvalue"
> android:textSize ="@dimen/mydimenvalue"
> ```

Comment: Thanks Anthea will try it

Comment: Anthea I tried but it doesn't work. The traditional method of res\layout\small etc and then supports screen in the manifest works.

My question is can I create a single layout which can support all screen formats